# How to automate single line code, with changes in input?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have created a variable named 'j' which has some values and I want my code to pick one value at a time and execute.
I tried writing code but it does not work. I'm sharing my code please see when it can be improved.

```
j = ['0', '1', '3', '4', '6', '7', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67']
```

`for i in j:
    labels('i') = mne.read_labels_from_annot('sub-CC721377_T1w', parc='aparc', subjects_dir=subjects_dir)['i']
done`

Comment: Have you considered using a function?

Comment: Don't try to write the results to `label1`, `label2`, etc. Just create a list `label` and use `label[0]`, `label[1]` etc.

Answer (score 0):

According to the MNE [documentation](https://martinos.org/mne/stable/generated/mne.read_labels_from_annot.html#mne.read_labels_from_annot), the function `read_labels_from_annot` returns a list of labels.

Thus, instead of indexing the result with `...)[0]` at the end, you should just capture the entire list:

```
labels = mne.read_labels_from_annot(...)
```

This would capture a list of labels, rather than a single label, which would have the effect of 'indexing at the end "[0]" from 0 - 67'.

You asked about adding all the results together into a `label_all` variable. You didn't specify (and I don't know anything about the MNE package), so it's not clear: do the labels ever repeat? Is is possible that "lab123" will occur in every input file? If so, should the `label_all` store multiple copies of the same value, or just the unique label names?

I think something like this is what you're after:

```
import mne

def get_labels_for_subject(sub, *, hemi='both', parc='aparc', **kwargs):
    """Get MNE labels for a given subject. **kwargs allows passing named 
    parameters like subjects_dir, regexp, and others that default to None."""

    labels = mne.read_labels_from_annot(sub, hemi=hemi, parc=parc, **kwargs)
    return labels

# List of all the subjects
subjects = [
    'sub-CC721377_T1w',
    'sub-next???',
]

label_all = []

for s in subjects:
    label_all.extend(get_labels_for_subject(s, subjects_dir='.'))

print("Got labels:", label_all)
```